# Problems occured while installing sendmail

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, postfix

I have been trying to install send mail recently(I have been using postfix with mailutils previously) and the first time I tried to install it, it took all night than I canceled it in the morning and said :

```
dpkg: error processing package sendmail-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sensible-mda:
 sensible-mda depends on sendmail-bin | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package sendmail-bin is not configured yet.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package sendmail-bin which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package sensible-mda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sendmail:
 sendmail depends on sendmail-bin; however:
  Package sendmail-bin is not configured yet.
 sendmail depends on sensible-mda; however:
  Package sensible-mda is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sendmail (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-bin
 sensible-mda
 sendmail
```

Using `dpkg --configure -a` does not solve the problem. It only brings up the same errors.

Comment: Go through these commands : http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: What command do you use to install it?

Comment: @derHugo. I only used `sudo apt install postfix mailutils`